# How to write a typesafe union typed save metod

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript-class

I'd like to create a generic http service, and I'd like to have a `save(value)` like method that calls `create(value)` or `update(value)` underneath. The twist is that I want to optionally to configure the type of the value `create` accepts which can be totatlly different than the update value.

Like this:

```js
class HttpService {
  create(model) {
    ...
  }
  update(model) {
    ... 
  }
  save(model) {
    if(model.id === null || model.id === undefined) {
      return this.create(model);
    }
    return this.update(model);
  }
}
```

The generic type of this is something like this:

```js
class HttpService<I, E, C> {
  create(model: E | C) : E;
  update(model: E) : E;
  save(model: E | C): E;
}
```

I want to merge these two cases:

1. The create and update share the same interface where the entity's (call it `E`) id with the property name `Id`. This id is generic (call it `I`) and it's type is `I | null | undefined`. This interface extends the `MaybeEntity<I>` because of this.
2. The create and update accepts different interface. When using the ceate function it should accept interface `C extends NotEnity` where the `Id` is absent, `null` or `undefined` and returns an `E`. The update only accepts `E extends Entity<I>` where the `Id` must be `I`

I've tried with these types but I've failed

```js
export type Id = 'id';
export type Entity<I> = Record<Id, I>;
export type NotEntity = Partial<Record<Id, null>>;
export type MaybeEntity<I> = Partial<Record<Id, I | null >>;

class HttpService<I, E extends MaybeEntity<I>, C extends NotEntity = (E & NotEntity )> {
  create(model: C | E & NotEntity) { }

  update(model: E & Entity<I>) {}

  save(model: C | E) {
    return model.id === undefined && model.id === null
      ? this.create(model)
      : this.update(model);
  }
}
```

Comment: Typescript seed 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCSATOBeOByASwzwG4AoUSWBZVAUQDsYCkAeNAPhzgCVgBjaBnYYANOg7lK0eEhRwAchBiNmSbgAUAhrAJaANqz6CowzOIYBXffo6SK4GTXkBZLYgBGwVS0TsuuNq6BkYCQiLiaHAAPnBWNnB25A5U8Pz6WgDOmXAAEjAwYADKwFAAbgT8wOzidHCgMMAMGDlunt5Mvv7iAML1II3NOUoqneq4ABR1AGSKyj7qAJRcAN5kcHD8UMBajRMAthAYwPoAXHB9sTNzo2qIi3ArcAC+ZOtwlmAYu8AHRyfna4LPycB4rV7vTJaMq-Q7HM4XGJwOhg94bbYwSxQBj4Ih4OAEHFwk5waazYn6AB0RBw2FwlmawAAZoTgFgyXAKdSsHTcPF9GiNnAAPwIAAWBEylK2Oz2FMWgo25xgEqln2+cv++kW5A2r2eQA

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE.** Sorry if I missunderstood your problem. I created an interface (it could be a type although) for the `Entity`. I also created a type for `NotEntity` which is only an entity without an `id`. The class takes an `Entity` then checks the type of `id` in save function, if it is `undefined` or its value equals to `null` then we are talking about a not entity and call to the save function. Otherwise we have an `id` and we can call to the update function. I'm sure there is a better way to do it, but this could be an initial way to your own.

```js
export interface Entity<I> {
  id?: I,
  [key: string]: any
}

export type NotEntity<I> = Omit<Entity<I>, 'id'>;

export class HttpService<I, E extends Entity<I>> {
  create(model: NotEntity<I>) {}

  update(model: Entity<I>) {}

  save(model: E) {
    return typeof model.id ===  undefined || model.id === null
      ? this.create(model)
      : this.update(model);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's missing in your code is that the ternary statement in `save` isn't understanding the limitations that it is imposing and isn't refining the type of the `model` in the `true` and `false` branches.

Typescript can understand simple property check conditions, but when you combine them with `&&` it stops trying.  We need to extract this multiple condition check into its own type guard function and tell Typescript what it means to be `true` or `false`.

```
const hasId = <E extends MaybeEntity<any>>( model: E ): model is E & {id: NonNullable<E['id']>} => {
  return 'id' in model && model.id === undefined && model.id === null;
}
```

Right now you are allowing `C` to require arbitrary properties which are required for creation but aren't present in the created object.  Is this really necessary?  It is possible to support this, but would require more advanced checking.

You are also saying that `create` cannot be called if an `id` is present.  Is this really necessary, or can the `id` just be ignored? (for example, if cloning an existing object to a new id).

Assuming both of those are not strictly necessary, this code will work:

```
export class HttpService<I, E extends MaybeEntity<I>> {
  create(model: E) { }

  update(model: E & Entity<I>) { }

  save(model: E) {
    return hasId(model)
      ? this.update(model)
      : this.create(model);
  }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/GmZ2Dm)